# How to get fixed cell value, not formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell in Google Sheets, with `=NOW()` formula in it. All I need - to get the value, generated by formula (22.01.2014 15:23:51), not the formula by itself.

If I try: `var nowtime = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValues();`,
I get `={DATE(2014\1\22)+TIME(15\19\13)}`, but not the numbers.

How to do it with Google Script syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this little snippet to do that.

### Code

```
function getCell(startcol, startrow) {
  // prepare string
  var str = String.fromCharCode(64 + startcol) + startrow;

  // retrieve value
  var vCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(str).getValue();

  // return content cell
  return vCell;  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The first parameter of the custom function passes on the column index, as an integer. The *var str* creates from the column integer and the row index a string (A1 notation). Then the value is retrieved and returned to the spreadsheet.

This piece of code will retrieve any value.

Add the script under Tools>Script editor. Press the "bug" button to validate the script and you're on the go !!

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm a little late to the party here, but you could try `.getDisplayValue()` instead of `.getValue()` or  `.getDisplayValues()` instead of `.getValues()`  That will give you the result of the formula instead of the formula itself.

I just had the same problem and the above solution worked for me.